# Selenium with Chrome

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, selenium

I'm fresher of selenium automation testing, i have zero knowledge in selenium, now i tried selenium with chrome browser using eclipse but  i'm facing following error please help me .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/Capabilities

 at LaunchApplication.main(LaunchApplication.java:13)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.Capabilities

 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 1 more
```

Comment: can you share your selenium code?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error and happens when the class is available while compiling and cannot be found by JVM in runtime, you may try these options:

1) The class is not available in Java Classpath.

2) You might be running your program using jar command and class was not defined in manifest file's ClassPath attribute.

3) Any start-up script is overriding Classpath environment variable.

4) Because `NoClassDefFoundError` is a subclass of `java.lang.LinkageError` it can also come if one of it dependency like native library may not available.

4) Check for `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` in your log file. `NoClassDefFoundError` due to the failure of static initialization is quite common.

5) If you are working in Java EE environment than the visibility of Class among multiple Classloader can also cause `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, see examples and scenario section for detailed discussion.

Comment: Thanks lot.. while running jar using command prompt C:\Selenium>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar chromedriver.exe
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed m
ain parameter 'chromedriver.exe' but no main parameter was defined
        at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.getMainParameter(JCommander.java:914)